# How can I maintain different ignore lists at different folder levels in Subversion?

Tags: svn

Given a Subversion project where certain patterns are always to be ignored,

```
*.log
*.idx
```

and certain patterns are ignored only in, e.g., the project root,

```
*.out
```

how can I maintain both lists in a single `svn:ignore` property?

To maintain the project-wide list, I would recursively apply the root folder's `svn:ignore` property whenever I change it.  But that would include patterns which should only be ignored in the root.

If I *don't* apply it recursively, though, then the other patterns will not be ignored in subfolders.

**UPDATE:** If you're used to Mercurial (like I am), you might suggest putting paths in the root's ignore list, like

```
*/*.idx
```

or

```
*\*.idx
```

Neither of these works for me in the latest Subversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mechanisms to work with ignores in Subversion:

- Global Ignores. Pattern may be added to the list of `global-ignores` in the subversion configuration. Applies globally to all the projects. Generally speaking defining too much of global-ignores is a bad thing.
- `svn:ignore` property. By setting `svn:ignore` property one can define list of files or folders ignored in the directory for which this property is defined.

Both global ignores and `svn:ignore` property work not with regular expressions but use patterns complying to the [fnmatch](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch) pattern syntax. Which defines only three types of the wild cards `?`, `*`, and `[]`. You may play with `ls` to feel how these patterns work.

Subversion properties may be set recursively. This will work for `*.idx` and `*.log` files:

```
$ svn st
? test.log
? test.idx
? recursive/test.log
```

Create a file `ignores` with two lines:

```
*.log
*.idx
```

Then set `svn:ingore` property recursively:

```
$ svn propset --recursive svn:ignore -F ingores  .
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'recursive'
$ rm ignores
$ svn st --no-ignores
I test.log
I test.idx
I recursive/test.log
```

After that edit `svn:ignore` property in the project root:

```
$ svn propedit svn:ignore PROJECT_ROOT
```

and add exclusion for the `*.out` pattern.

Given that:

> If I don't apply it recursively, though, then the other patterns will not be ignored in subfolders.

The only way is to add such patterns to the global-ignores.

Some notes:

- After setting `svn:ignore` property may be deleted recursively with
  the help of the `svn propdel -R ...`
- This way of adding ignores does not feel flexible (to me). For instance when creating new folder one should remember to set
  project-wide `svn:ignore` property.
- Recursive propset should be done early. It deletes old value of the property being set.
- Major plus is that ignores are rarely edited.
- Editing properties recursively seems to be easier when done through the GUI tools

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the reply.  I agree that global ignores should be avoided, and I would like these to travel with the project.  So I'm not really sure what you're suggesting here.  It is not sufficient to add patterns to the root, as these **do not** apply to subdirectories automatically.

Comment: Thanks again, and +1 for all the details.  I have to accept this answer because it's clear that there's no satisfactory solution (as you say).  It would be much better if `svn:ignore` were inherited and additive, or better yet if it worked like it does in Mercurial, where it's both simpler and more powerful.  As it is, I'll just adapt the project so that this method will suit.

Answer (score 0):

Read about propset and propedit commands and find **One Big Difference**

- propset can be recursive
- propedit can't

Thus, you can

- use propset -R in repo-root with two repo-wide patterns (check results to see it populated over tree)
- with propedit edit svn-properties of root-only folder and add local ignore-pattern *.out

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Maybe I'm missing something here, but if I do as you suggest, won't the local pattern simply be propagated to all folders next time I change the project-wide list?  I know how to apply the property non-recursively, but that of course defeats the purpose.

Comment: propedit can't work in recursive mode. Only propset affect all tree

Comment: I get that, but they're still editing the same value.  The problem is that you can't apply one list recursively and another list non-recursively.  Hence the maintenance problem.

Comment: @harpo - can't see problem. *Add* non-recursive property with edit to  previously created recursive: it works in my test

Comment: Yes, I can add to the value, but what happens when the recursive list changes?  The non-recursive part is still there.  If it were just a one-time situation, there would be no problem.  I'm talking about maintaining the configuration over time.

Comment: @harpo - with propedit you have to edit all dirs in tree. Maybe you'll can to use propset ober propset (TBT!) and it will remove **all previous** settings